# what is the best way to create dynamic HTML with ASP code behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, code-behind

I am using a bootstrap modal, however the content within the modal will be dynamic in two ways. First by the data that gets pulled from the database, then dynamic in the sense that the JavaScript will only make visible to the user the data relevant to the button they pressed.

What is the best way to fill the body of the modal with dynamic HTML, the only way I can think of is using a string to fill the innerHtml attribute of the modal div. Set up of the body would end up like

```
<div class="modal_body">
  <section id="1">
    <div id="stuff1"/>
    <div id="stuff2"/>
  </section>
  <setion id="2">
  ...
  </section>
  ...
</div>
```

The number of sections and number of "stuff" divs within sections is totally dynamic. They would all be defaultly set to hidden too, the one made visible when the modal is triggered will depend on which button triggered it.

Is there a clean way to write that HTML in the code behind without filling the C# files with HTML strings? For example the section div's technically have a common template, and so do the stuff divs. Is there functionality in asp to have html templates and dynamically fill placeholders?

Comment: MVC or Webforms? There is a solution but different for each framework.

Comment: in Webforms you can create an Control and add there the controls and html you want, the control can take as parameter a Model and populate it with data. And you can add it dynamicaly in main Page per model.

Answer (score 0):

MVC and Razor will help, eg

```
<html>
<body>
@for(var i = 10; i < 21; i++)
    {<p>Line @i</p>}
</body>
</html>
```

Lots of help on the Web

Also, have a look at a clientside MVVM / MVC / M??? framework.

I would have a look at AngularJS (by google), get your data as JSON then have code like

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller" class="modal_body">
  <div ng-repeat="section in sections" >
    <div ng-repeat="stuff in section.stuff">
     {{stuff.value}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your json would be generated from a strongly typed c# class.

It works very well with bootstrap and you don't need to be strong on javascript, well.. I am not and I (part of a team) , we have just completed a decent portal.

https://angularjs.org/

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ (Check out some of the examples)

Hope this helps.

Comment: for showing and hiding you can do things like ng-show="stuff.show" and change the value of stuff from the server or in javascript.